# Correct handling for objects and lights in 3D space - OpenGL

Tags: opengl, render, light

I am trying to get everything up and running with my engine but am having trouble figuring out what order to add objects and lights to get everything rendered correctly.

I set up my projection and modelview matrix in my itialization:

```
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();                            

gluPerspective(75.0f,(GLfloat)width/(GLfloat)height, 0.1f , 1000.0f);

glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);                         
glLoadIdentity();
```

Then, when I am rendering geometry, I clear the buffer and load the identity matrix and update my camera.

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
glLoadIdentity();

// Camera updates
glRotatef(camera.anglePitch, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
glRotatef(camera.angleYaw, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
glTranslatef(-camera.position.x, -camera.position.y, -camera.position.z);

// Now render
level.render();
```

My view of my level is a camera, which I gather is eye coordinates moving around. I am trying to render objects and lights in my level and have them show up in the correct places.

I need to add the objects at specific points in the world. For instance, a torus at (10, 10, 25). Is there anything I need to do before I render this torus objects that will make them appear correctly at 10, 10, 25? Do I need to render and then translate them for instance?

Also, part 2 has to do with lights. It is pretty much the same question. What consideration do I have to have when rendering say a light at 50, 50, 50? Can I just position the light normally or do again do I have to translate it to there? Or am I over thinking this?

Comment: There are a few things that are unclear about your question:
First, what origin are you referring to, the origin of the eye coordinate space or the object coordinate space?
Second, what do you mean by "rendering lights"? Are you referring to how your polygons are shaded, or do you want to render an object that will look like a light source? (sorry for the initial mixup in posting the comment, I mistakenly saved it without writing it :)

Comment: Sorry. I tried to avoid that. Please tell me what I can clarify.

Comment: @jcage Let me know if you have any more questions. I am trying to word  everything correctly. Where I have the level data which are absolute coordinates i.e. triangle at (2.5, 1.2, 10.2) the objects I need to render just have their mesh coordinates and then locations where they need to go. How do I render those objects in their correct places? Something along the lines of loading the objects and then translating them to their specific places? I am really not sure. Hope that clears up my question.

Comment: Well, the way I would do it would be to translate the coordinates of the objects, by adding to each of them the desired location of that object. Would not bother with translations through the modelview matrix, just perform plain additions of vectors and render them just like the level object is rendered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the issue, I would agree that you are overthinking this. The transformations from glTranslate and glRotate are applied to the modelview matrix, by which all your vertices are multiplied to provide the eye coordinates that will later be clipped in projection. The same transformations are applied to your lights as well.

You can also use glPopMatrix and glPushMatrix to apply different states of the modelview matrix to different vertices.

I would also refer you to question 9.070 in http://www.opengl.org/resources/faq/technical/transformations.htm

Comment: Okay. So for instance, I load an object from a file and want to add it at (100, 100, 0). I simply load the object and then translate it to (100, 100, 0) and apply any rotations that I would need and that's it? What about multiple objects that all need to be rendered at different spots. How would I do this? To make it simple, let's imagine I was rendering 5 circle models all at different locations. What would the loop look like for rendering these five circles. Can you give me an example? Thank you.

Comment: Also, I really apologize for the confusing wording. What you wrote is exactly what I need, I am just curious as to how glTranslate and glRotate would fit into a function rendering multiple objects at different locations.

Comment: I believe that doing this with the modelview matrix, would require rebuilding the matrix for each object. so the cycle would be glLoadIdentity-> glRotate&Transform -> obj1.render -> glLoadIdentity -> glRotate&Transform -> obj2.render and so forth. There's a chance I might be wrong about this, but I think this would be the case